# C sed linenumbers on same line

Tags: c, sed, execvp

I made a small program that puts line numbers in front of each line in a file! This is working perfectly fine, but their is just one problem. I get this as result:

1

Text one

2

Text two

3

Text three

But I want the output to me like:

```
1 Text one
2 Text two
3 Text three
```

I use this code to execute the sed functionality:

```
char* exec[] = { "sed", "/./=", NULL }; 
execvp(exec[0], exec);
```

I think I need to change the exec[], but I don't know in what way!

Many thanks :D

Comment: They look the same (what you get and what you said you want)

Comment: Two questions: 1) If you use sed, why in C?   2) If you're supposed to write it in C, why use sed?

Comment: [mu](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mu_(negative)#.22Unasking.22_the_question). Why are you writing a C program just to spawn `sed`? Why not print the lines numbers from the C program using [getline](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getline.3.html) to read the line? Of if you must use an external program, why `sed`? Why not use `cat` with the `-n` option that prints line numbers?

Comment: What about poor, neglected `nl` whose sole purpose is to add line numbers to a file?

Comment: @CharlesBailey +1 How come no one ever told me such a thing where out there, waiting to be used?! Now `cat -n` feels just so... why not `nl`? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
sed 'N;N;N;s/\n//g;s/[0-9]*/& /' YourFile
```

remove \n (base on a structure of 4 line per real line, then add a space after first number

but why using sed to deconstruct what could be done easily construct directly otherwise (cat -n, grep -n, ...) ?